# Android : code not functioning as intended

Tags: java, android, xml

[Screenshot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wbwh.jpg)

I'm trying to display information about a business.
However the phone number is being displyed in wrong place ( ie top right)
According to me, It should come right of call image.
What is wrong with code phonenumber_text_view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.rafi.ansarenglishschool.MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ansar_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ansar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ansar_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ansar_image_view"
    android:text="Ansar English School"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:background="#2962ff"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/call_image_view"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/call1"
    android:layout_below="@id/ansar_text_view"
    />


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/phonenumber_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/call_image_view"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="123456789"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />*

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/location_image_view"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/location1"
    android:layout_below="@id/call_image_view"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/disc_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/location_image_view"
    android:text="Ansar English  is a private school run by Ansari Charitable trust located in Perumpilavu."
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: These types of questions usually fair better when you include an image of what you are getting along with maybe what you expect.

Comment: Ok. Iv included one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `android:layout_below` attribute to align it properly like following:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/phonenumber_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/call_image_view"
        android:layout_below="@id/ansar_text_view"
        android:text="123456789"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

PS: There is a `*` right after above `TextView` in your xml file

Comment: Thanks. so why didn't android:layout_toRightOf="@id/call_image_view" work ? Theoretically it should come right of child call_image right ?

Comment: It did work, thats how its aligned horizontally, towards the right of call button. Along with that, we also need to align it vertically therefore we need `android:layout_below`.